# is there callback methods for logout facebook button in android?

Tags: android, facebook

I want to perform some task when user clicked logout button and at the time if the user is logged out perform some task(say to open another activity)

```
CallbackManager mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
//                AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
//                Boolean value = accessToken.isExpired();
                Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

                if (profile != null) {
                    String userId = profile.getId();
                    String userName = profile.getName();

                    Log.d("userId", userId);
                    Log.d(TAG, "name : " + userName);

//                    sessionManager.createLoginSessionViaApp(userId, userName);
//                    disableTheAppSignInRegisterButtonsIfLoggedin();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.d(TAG, "status cancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "status error login");
            }
        };
        fbLoginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
        fbLoginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, mCallback);
```

I've done this so far for login

Answer (score 1):

You can use the AccessTokenTracker to track logouts. It will call onCurrentAccessTokenChanged, and the currentAccessToken will be null if the user has logged out.